# how to horizontally align different div inside a div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have outer div inside that there are two div one containing image and other containing some p tags
but they didn't align horizontally below is my code please answer with proper explanation and code to do so. I am beginner in css and also explain me why "vertical align:middle" is not working . some space is also there above the div image .

```
 .a10-outter-box {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-2 {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-2 p {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-1 img {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: auto;
            width: 80px;
            border-radius: 60px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-1 {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```
<div class="a10-outter-box">
        <div class="a10-inner-box-1">
            <img src="avtar.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="a10-inner-box-2">
            <p>hemant rawat</p>
            <p>offline</p>
            <p>last 1 hr ago</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Title is "how to horizontally align" but then you ask why `vertical-align: middle` isn't working. Are you trying to horizontally center the content or vertically center the image to the text block?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped your inner-content with a div, then changed your outer div to a `display:flex` with `justify-content:center` instead.

Is this what you meant?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8yvhgk9t/7/

```html
<div class="a10-outter-box">
     <div class="inner">
     
       <div class="a10-inner-box-1">
            <img src="avtar.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="a10-inner-box-2">
            <p>hemant rawat</p>
            <p>offline</p>
            <p>last 1 hr ago</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

```css
 .a10-outter-box {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: flex;
            padding: 5px;
            justify-content:center;
        }
        .a10-inner-box-2 {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-2 p {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-1 img {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: auto;
            width: 80px;
            border-radius: 60px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        .a10-inner-box-1 {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

Comment: `justify-content` is the wrong property here.  Think about what `vertical-align: middle` is supposed to do.  Then you realize that you got the wrong property and that you only got half of the solution.

Comment: OP wanted to center it horizontally, not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the height of an element is auto which means that it will be calculated to `fit-content`. In other words, an element is only as high as the content.

Centering vertically requires the height of an element to be larger than the content itself!

The easiest way is to use Flexbox where you can by default use `align-items: center` to vertically center an element. Note, that the height of the parent element still needs to be larger than the child element itself:

```css
.parent {
  /* needs a height higher then the child */
  height: 30vh;
  
  /* use Flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}



/* for visualisation only */
.parent {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```